# Unclear purpose of return in a function

Tags: c, function, return

I recently started studying C and stubled upon this function.

```
int is_prime(int n) {

    int d;

    for (d = 2; d * d <= n; d++)
        if (n % d == 0)
            return 0;

    return n >= 2;
}
```

While I understand the general purpose and functioning of it (it checks if the argument is a prime number), I don't understand what this line

```
return n >= 2;
```

does exactly.
Does it only return n, only if it is `>= 2` ? and what would happen if n is < 2?
Would anyone be so kind to explain? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns the value of the expression `n >= 2;`.

Now, since the expression involves a comparison operator, it can evaluate to `0` which means *False*, or `1` which means *True*.

---

You can get a clue about this from the previous `return` statement. `return 0`, which is returning `0`, which actually means *False*.

---

**NOTE:** C does not have any concept of *True* or *False*. In C *True* is represented by any numeric value not equal to 0 and *False* is represented by 0.

Comment: There is no such thing as `False` in C. Your answer is misleading.

Comment: @FUZxxl, Is it better now.

Comment: No. First, there is no such thing as a “comparison expression.” There are “comparison operators,” one of which is `>=` though. Second, please make clear that *true* and *false* are concepts, not parts of the C programming language which does not define these two.

Comment: @FUZxxl, Thanks for the suggestion. Is it better?

Comment: Yes. Although not putting *true* and *false* in monospace font (like `this` is monospace) would have been enough for my second complaint. Monospace indicates “this is code,” but it's important to make clear that true and false are not code from a didactical point of view.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound pedantic but I just really care about answers being precise and not misleading in any way, especially if written for beginners who may learn wrong things from an imprecise answer.

Comment: @FUZxxl, Not at all. Suggestions like this make things clear, for the OP, for me as well as anyone who reads this later.

Answer (score 1):

Like all other places where an expression is present, it evaluates the expression and, for the function's result, returns the value.'

```
n >= 2
```

is true if n is 2, 3, 4, ...  and is false if n is 1, 0, -1, -2, ...